# selenium webdriver is stuck after downloading and saving a pdf file in firefox

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download pdf from pubmed central using selenium webdriver in python. The code is provided below which downloads the pdf fine but, does not quit automatically. i.e. it is sort of stuck executing `browser.get(href)` line.
What could be the reason?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
ncbi_url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/"

download_dir = "pdf_downloaded"

if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
    os.mkdir(download_dir)
    
options = Options()
options.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
options.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.path.abspath(download_dir))
options.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
options.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

###############################################################################
def download_pmc_pdf(pmcid_key):
    pmc_url = ncbi_url + "pmc/articles/" + pmcid_key + "/"
    browser.get(pmc_url)
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        pdf_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pmc-sidebar__formats li a')))
        
        # Iterate over all links and navigate to the link containing '.pdf' in the href attribute
        for link in pdf_links:
            href = link.get_attribute('href')
            if '.pdf' in href:
                browser.get(href)
                break  # exit the loop as we have found the PDF link
        print("line beofre browser.quit()")
        browser.quit()  # quit the browser outside the loop
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


    
###############################################################################
pmcid = "2788555"            
download_pmc_pdf(pmcid)
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute a JavaScript code that opens the pdf link in a new window/tab. After that, just closed this newly opened window/tab and continued with the script execution. Here is the updated code:

```
import os
import time
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ncbi_url = "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/"

download_dir = "pdf_downloaded"

if not os.path.exists(download_dir):
    os.mkdir(download_dir)
    
options = Options()
options.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
options.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.path.abspath(download_dir))
options.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/pdf')
options.set_preference('pdfjs.disabled', True)

###############################################################################
def download_pmc_pdf(pmcid_key):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    pmc_url = ncbi_url + "pmc/articles/" + pmcid_key + "/"
    browser.get(pmc_url)
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        pdf_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pmc-sidebar__formats li a')))

        # Iterate over all links and navigate to the link containing '.pdf' in the href attribute
        for link in pdf_links:
            href = link.get_attribute('href')
            if '.pdf' in href:
                # Open the pdf link in a new window
                browser.execute_script(f'window.open("{href}","_blank");')
                break

        time.sleep(15)  # delay for 10 seconds
        # After the file is downloaded:
        with open(f'{download_dir}/file_mapping.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([pmcid_key, os.path.basename(href)])
        ## Switch to the new window and close it 
        ## (this is a hack to deal with bowser freezing upon downloading)
        browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
        browser.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        browser.quit()  # quit the browser outside the loop    
###############################################################################
pmcid = "2788555"   
download_pmc_pdf(pmcid)
```